# How to program a msp430 without bootloader or ISP connector?

Tags: usb, programming, msp430, surface-mount

I'm looking for a way to program a msp430 microcontroller in-circuit and with all the components SMD, including the ISP connector. Could, in this case, USB still be an option?

Comment: You can look at the schematic for the Launchpad. I think there's another MCU to provide the USB interface. You'll either need a second MCU, a bootloader or both.

Comment: But don't I need to program that MCU in order to work properly?

Comment: Just add an ISP connector and use a TI MSP430 FET.

Comment: But the ISP connector is not surface mount.

Comment: www.tag-connect.com then your ISP connector is no mount. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSP430 launchpad and other TI's evaluation boards have a proprietary JTAG emulation circuit onboard, which is consisting of a USB connected microcontroller on one side, and connected to the target device's programming interface on the other. As said, the firmware for this emulator is proprietary and closed, so the only way to use it is by connecting such a board to your circuit. Or build a JTAG emulator yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I note this question was posted nearly two years ago, however, for those who end up here in the future, TI has published a document regarding the JTAG programer. It is, in fact, not closed.
The documentation and sample code can be found in this document: [SLAU320X.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau320)